# Orthogonal Array Testing

Tags: testing

I'm newbie to Software Testing. Can anyone pls help me to understand

"***Orthogonal Array Testing***"

I went to some articles but they are just mentioning like , it's a kind of Blackbox Testing Technique". Need more info on it. Pls provide that.

Comment: Have you [googled](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=orthogonal+array+software+testing&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C1) that? (google scholar is your friend).

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonal Array Testing Strategy (or "OATS") is a test case selection approach that selects a highly-varied set of test scenarios in order to find as many bugs as possible in as few tests as possible.  It is a powerful test design approach that is gaining in popularity because it has proved to increase efficiency and effectiveness of testing in many different types of testing contexts.  Disclaimer: I created [Hexawise](http://hexawise.com), a tool that generates orthogonal array-like sets of software tests so I may be biased about the benefits of this test design approach).

Using OATS, testers can strategically identify a manageable number of high-priority tests in situations where there might be thousands, millions, billions, or gazillions of possible permutations to choose from.  OATS is based on the knowledge that the vast majority of defects in production today can be detected by testing for every possible 2-way (or pairwise) combination of test inputs - and that defects that could only be triggered by interactions involving 3 or more specific inputs are quite rare.  (Google reports by Dr. Rick Kuhn for specific data supporting this; he's been involved in many studies; several of them are summarized in the articles below).

Here are some clear introductory materials about OATS (and the extremely-closely-related topic of pairwise test design):

- [Pairwise Testing] (http://www.developsense.com/pairwiseTesting.html)
  by Michael Bolton describes the concepts quite clearly.  Mid-way
  through the article, he correctly and clearly draws a distinction
  between the very closely-related topics of orthogonal arrays vs. all-pairs AKA "pairwise" testing that
  most articles gloss over.
- [Combinatorial Software Testing]
  (https://hexawise.com/Combinatorial-Software-Testing-Case-Studies-IEEE-Computer-Kuhn-Kacker-Lei-Hunter.pdf)
  by Rick Kuhn (NIST), Raghu Kacker (NIST), Yu Lei (UTexas at
  Arlington) and Justin Hunter (Hexawise).
- A fun image-rich presentation on the subject is [Combinatorial
  Software Test Design - Beyond Pairwise Testing]
  (http://www.slideshare.net/JustinHunter/combinatorial-software-testdesignbeyondpairwisetesting).

You might also find this related StackExchange question to be of interest. In my answer to the question, I provide an explanation for why pairwise solutions (AKA AllPairs) solutions are usually superior to orthogonal array-based solutions for software testers.  When you use a pairwise test generator, you will be able to generate more efficient sets of tests that meet your coverage goal with fewer tests: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/775/systematic-approaches-to-selection-of-test-data/780#780

The above materials will give you a relatively thorough understanding of the basic principles. There is, unfortunately, not enough written by people about how to apply these techniques in different testing contexts; that's where things get interesting and valuable. Applying this test design technique well takes analytical skill, development of some new techniques and strategies, as well as practice. For anyone wanting a deeper dive into the topic, I'd suggest the articles and presentations at [pairwisetesting.com](http://pairwisetesting.com) as well as [help.hexawise.com](http://help.hexawise.com) and [training.hexawise.com](http://training.hexawise.com).

Comment: Have this method some proofs of effectiveness? Can I miss some important test case combinations if I use this?